# Implement a reset button per facet

Tags: 8, search

I'm using Search API with Facets and a view to display the results. Everything works as expected but I would like to have a reset button per facet, that could be used as a "*Show all*" button.

For the moment I'm using `facets_preprocess_facets_item_list(&$variables)` to create an extra item on the top of every list, eg.

- Facet 1 : Region
   All regions, Region 1, Region 2, ...
- Facet 2 : Financial support
   All financial supports, Financial support 1,
  Financial support 2, ...
- Facet 3 : Status
   All statuses,
  Status 1, Status 2, ...
- Facet 4 : Sector
   All sectors, Sector
  1, Sector 2, ...

To construct the "*All ...*" links, I'm getting the parameters of the current page and I clean up the filters. For example if the user clicks on the "*All financial supports*" [facet 2] link while the current page parameters are
`../organizations?[facet 1]organizations%5B0%5D=region%3A18&[facet 2]organizations%5B1%5D=financial_support%3A1&[facet 3]organizations%5B2%5D=status%3A10&[facet 4]organizations%5B3%5D=sector%3A28`
the parameters become
 `../organizations?[facet 1]organizations%5B0%5D=region%3A18&[facet 2][facet 3]organizations%5B2%5D=status%3A10&[facet 4]organizations%5B3%5D=sector%3A28`

It works, but I'm not conviced that this is the best solution because I've managed to dramaticaly slow down the display of the view and, well... it's not very elegant.

Do you know if there is another, more Drupalish solution to implement a reset button per facet?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

1. Navigate to the facet setting page (`/admin/config/search/facets/facet_name/edit`)
2. under `widget` set it to `List of Checkboxes` or `List of Links` (not sure what you are using)
3. Within `List of Checkboxes setting` or `List of Links Setting`, there should be an option `Show Reset Link`.
4. Enabled it and it will show a `Reset Text` input box where you can add `Reset Facet` or whatever you need.
5. Apply other settings and click save.

[image: list of checkboxes for facets]